# how to install the package to the default python in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, package

I am new in ubuntu and Python. I installed Python 2.7.9 manually in ubuntu. After that I found that there already has the default python 2.7.9 in Ubuntu. Every time when I type "python" in terminal, it will always open the default python for me. But there is some problems on the arrow input in the default python. So I wanted to install the readline package by typing "pip install realine"(solution after some googling). realine package was installed successfully:

```
pip install readline
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): readline in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

But it seems that it was not installed in the default python:

```
$python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Feb 16 2015, 01:18:32) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import readline
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named readline
```

Is it because that the realine was not installed in the default one but the other? How can I install the package to the default python?

Comment: What does `which python` show?

Comment: does pip3 and python3 commands works?

Comment: When you say "installed python manually" do you mean via apt-get or building from source?

Comment: which python shows :
/usr/local/bin/python
@DanielRoseman

Comment: actually I want to learn python2 now. But python3 works fine:) @Yair.R

Comment: I built from source.@Trengot